# Git não ignora certos subdiretórios

Tags: git

Recentemente iniciei um [projeto pessoal](https://github.com/quatroka/docmylife) para prática, e dentre uma das coisas que queria fazer é ter a pasta "src" contendo a fonte do projeto, porém toda vez que tentava fazer com que alguma parte de dentro desse diretório fosse ignorada pelo git, isto não ocorria? Tem haver com o nome da pasta?

Comment: Provavelmente não. Mas não tem como saber qual é o problema sem você descrever exatamente o que fez. Você pode ter errado alguma coisa.

Comment: Pablo, eu realizei um teste com seu projeto e parece que está ignorando sim os arquivos: http://prntscr.com/co8r82 . Poderia nos mostrar um caso que de errado ou um teste prático para nós?

Answer (score 2):

O Git controla arquivos, não pastas! Você pode testar isso criando uma pasta vazia e usando o commando:

```
git add *
```

Você verá que ele não adiciona a pasta ao staging.

O Git funciona com ponteiros para arquivos. E é somente com esses que você tem que se preocupar, então se quiser ignorar todos os arquivos de uma pasta você terá que fazer um regex:

> [Bb]in/

Que ignora todos arquivos (dll, obj, ...) na pasta Bin, começando ela com b ou B.

Referências interessantes para .gitignore:

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

https://github.com/github/gitignore

https://www.gitignore.io/